# Read composer extra config in regular code

Tags: php, composer-php

Using `composer config extra.foo bar` I can set custom data in `composer.json` and according to the [documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#extra) composer scripts can read it using `$event->getComposer()->getPackage()->getExtra()`

I would like to read it in a regular script (installed as a vendor binary) so the binary can be configured by the user, e.g. the binary requires a configuration file which I would like to put in `extra.config`.

Does composer support this or do I need to manually locate and parse `composer.json`? Is there a better solution for letting the user add configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation part you are refering to is about PHP-Scripts that get triggered as event-handler during a composer-invocation. So composer runs and provides the configuration-information while invoking the script.

When I understand your approach right, you want to be able to read the information while running your own script without composer. Then - as composer is not involved - composer can not provide any information.

So what you could do is read the composer.json file, parse it as JSON and get the for you relevant information from it.

But then it's nothing else than reading any other configuration file. So I would use a separate file for configuration. That would allow you to use a config also for projects that don't use composer (whyever one would want to do that...). And separation of concerns is also a good idea!

You perhaps might want to have a look at f.e. phpunit, phpcs or travis on how they handle their specific configuration issues within their scripts.

Comment: $composerFile = new \Composer\Config\JsonConfigSource('path/to/composer.json');